# Why is an original ArcMap-project twice as big as its copies?

Tags: arcmap, copy, file-size

I'm currently working with *ArcMap 10.7*. Therein, I regularly do `File` > `Save a Copy` of an existing *ArcMap*-project to create a copy for another *ArcMap* version. However, the file size of the original *ArcMap*-project (e.g. 3692 KB) is roughly double of the size of its copy (i.e. 1842 KB). The inconsistency of file size occurs in any direction, no matter if I copy *ArcMap 10.3* > *ArcMap 10.7*,  *ArcMap 10.5* > *ArcMap 10.3* etc. What's the reason that the original file is of double size of its copies?

Comment: It could be that the original has saved geoprocessing history in it which is not passed on when saving as a copy. Try clearing geoprocessing history in the original and save, is the size reduced?